# EBeanのquery cachingで異なるクエリの結果が返される

Tags: java, playframework

EBean（6.17.3）にて、クエリーキャッシングを行なったとき、
http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/features/l2caching/
異なるWHERE句のクエリに対して、キャッシュの値が返される場合があるようです。

いわゆるハッシュ値の衝突が起きているようなのですが、
あまりにも容易に衝突が起きているようなので、回避方法はないでしょうか？

サンプルはPostgreSQLですが、特にDBMLには依存しないと思います。

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  column_a character varying(10),
  column_b character varying(10),
  CONSTRAINT test_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE test_table
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

DBデータは以下です。

```
id;column_a;column_b
1;"SK08";"320"
2;"SK09";"310"
3;"SK01";"201"
4;"SK11";"101"
```

再現コードは以下です。
Entityの定義

```
import javax.persistence.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

/**
 * テストテーブル
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestTable extends Model {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "int8", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "column_a", columnDefinition = "varchar(10)", nullable = true)
    public String columnA;

    @Column(name = "column_b", columnDefinition = "varchar(10)", nullable = true)
    public String columnB;

}
```

検索部分のコードは以下です。
list1とlist2, list3とlist4が同じ値を返します。
（list2の検索時にlist1のキャッシュが返る。list4検索時にlist3のキャッシュが返る）

```
List<TestTable> list1 =
        Ebean.getServer(null)
        .find(TestTable.class)
        .setUseQueryCache(true)
        .where()
        .eq("columnA", "SK08")
        .eq("columnB", "320")
        .findList();

List<TestTable> list2 =
        Ebean.getServer(null)
        .find(TestTable.class)
        .setUseQueryCache(true)
        .where()
        .eq("columnA", "SK09")
        .eq("columnB", "310")
        .findList();

List<TestTable> list3 =
        Ebean.getServer(null)
        .find(TestTable.class)
        .setUseQueryCache(true)
        .where()
        .eq("columnA", "SK01")
        .eq("columnB", "201")
        .findList();

List<TestTable> list4 =
        Ebean.getServer(null)
        .find(TestTable.class)
        .setUseQueryCache(true)
        .where()
        .eq("columnA", "SK11")
        .eq("columnB", "101")
        .findList();
```

【追記 2016-11-07 16:50】

根本的には、以下のコードでhash1とhash2が同値になるのが原因です（EBeanのクエリーキャッシュのハッシュ値算出アルゴリズムを元に作成）。

```
int hash1 = 0;
hash1 = hash1 * 31 + "08".hashCode();
hash1 = hash1 * 31 + "20".hashCode();

int hash2 = 0;
hash2 = hash2 * 31 + "09".hashCode();
hash2 = hash2 * 31 + "10".hashCode();
```

String.hashCode()のコア部分は以下のような実装になっているようですので、char codeと桁ズレの組み合わせで容易にハッシュの衝突が起こるようです。

```
char val[] = value;

for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    h = 31 * h + val[i];
}
hash = h;
```

これは（最もキャッシュが有効に機能するはずの）コードテーブルでは普通に想定できる事態だと思います。（ふたつの文字列カラムでレコードが決定する場合）
問題が大きいですね･･･。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

今回の問題はEBean ORMのissue #869として登録され、Version 9.1.1で解決するようです。
https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/869

根本的な原因はハッシュキーを生成する際に31を用いた実装になっていたことです。

Answer (score 1):

結論としては、実用的な回避方法は（私の調べた限りでは）ありませんでした。

ただ、`eq()`メソッドの呼び出し順序を変更すれば、ハッシュの値を変えることができますので、誤ったキャッシュを回避することができます。

Ebean 8.1.1
MySQL 5.6.22

コードを変更して検証しました。

```
    DefaultOrmQuery<TestTable> query1 = (DefaultOrmQuery<TestTable>) Ebean.getServer(null)
            .find(TestTable.class)
            .setUseQueryCache(true)
            .where()
            .eq("columnA", "SK08")
            .eq("columnB", "320")
            .query();

    List<TestTable> list1 = query1
                    .findList();

    logger.info("query1:" + query1.queryHash().hashCode());
    TestTable t1 = list1.get(0);
    logger.info("list1:" + t1.id + " " + t1.columnA + " " + t1.columnB);

    DefaultOrmQuery<TestTable> query2 = (DefaultOrmQuery<TestTable>) Ebean.getServer(null)
            .find(TestTable.class)
            .setUseQueryCache(true)
            .where()
            .eq("columnA", "SK09")
            .eq("columnB", "310")
            .query();

    List<TestTable> list2 = query2
            .findList();

    logger.info("query2:" + query2.queryHash().hashCode());
    TestTable t2 = list2.get(0);
    logger.info("list2:" + t2.id + " " + t2.columnA + " " + t2.columnB);
```

この場合、クエリハッシュのハッシュコードはたしかに同一となり、キャッシュが利用されています。

```
情報: query1:-1961149220
情報: list1:1 SK08 320
14:48:20.021 [main] DEBUG org.avaje.ebean.cache.QUERY -    GET TestTable(HashQuery@8b1b3cdc) - hit
情報: query2:-1961149220
情報: list2:1 SK08 320
```

list2の`eq()`メソッドの順序を入れ替えます。

```
DefaultOrmQuery<TestTable> query2 = (DefaultOrmQuery<TestTable>) Ebean.getServer(null)
        .find(TestTable.class)
        .setUseQueryCache(true)
        .where()
        .eq("columnB", "310")
        .eq("columnA", "SK09")
        .query();
```

すると、キャッシュは利用されません。

```
情報: query1:-1961149220
情報: list1:1 SK08 320
14:50:11.574 [main] DEBUG org.avaje.ebean.cache.QUERY -    GET TestTable(HashQuery@35de6bfa) - cache miss
情報: query2:903769082
情報: list2:2 SK09 310
```

なお、エンティティクラスに`@Cache(enableQueryCache=true)`をつけています。

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
@Cache(enableQueryCache=true)
public class TestTable extends Model {
```

Comment: 再現テスト及びコメントありがとうございます。
ただ、これだけ簡単にhash collisionが起こってしまうと、
このケースが大丈夫であっても他のテーブルで同様の問題にぶつかる可能性が“高い”と思いました。
EBeanの問題（ほぼバグと呼んでいいものだと考えています）なので、
ハッシュ生成のアルゴリズムを変えるようなプルリクエストを送るしかないですかね…。